# How do I filter or limit the Rows used by apps script when pulling Column data?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, row

I'm new to apps script/javascript and am making a bot that posts slack updates from a constantly updating google sheet. It currently pulls from 3 specific columns and posts a string update with variables from those 3 columns. Since then we've added new rows which has created noise so I'm looking to limit or filter the rows it pulls from. For example, I'd only like to pull data from rows 6-10 or filter out anything that isn't row 6-10. How can I go about this?

I've tried inserting `and (getRow() == 4)` or variations on that and also trying to combine the parameter with the `if (e.range.getColumn() == 3) {` but have been getting syntax errors so have obviously missed something since I'm still inexperienced at javascript. Here's the current code section:

```
function sendReleaseUpdate(e) {
    if (e.range.getColumn() == 3) {
        var source = e.source;
        var row = e.range.getRow();
        var task = source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, 2, 1, 1).getValue();
        var assignee = source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, 1, 1, 1).getValue();
        var status = e.value;
        var url = "WEBHOOKGOESHERE"
        var payload = {
            text: "Live testing by " + assignee + " on " + task + " is " + status
        }

        var headers = {
            'Content-type': 'application/json'
        }
        var options = {
            headers: headers,
            method: 'POST',
            payload: JSON.stringify(payload)
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can change the sendReleaseUpdate function in your Google Apps Script code to filter or limit the rows from which you grab data by adding a condition to see if the row is within the specified range. Here is an illustration of how you can use it:

```js
function sendReleaseUpdate(e) {
    var targetSheetName = 'Sheet1'; // Update with your sheet name
    var startRow = 6;
    var endRow = 10;

    var sheet = e.source.getSheetByName(targetSheetName);
    var row = e.range.getRow();

    if (sheet.getName() === targetSheetName && row >= startRow && row <= endRow) {
        var task = sheet.getRange(row, 2).getValue();
        var assignee = sheet.getRange(row, 1).getValue();
        var status = e.value;
        var url = "WEBHOOKGOESHERE";
        var payload = {
            text: "Live testing by " + assignee + " on " + task + " is " + status
        };

        var headers = {
            'Content-type': 'application/json'
        };
        var options = {
            headers: headers,
            method: 'POST',
            payload: JSON.stringify(payload)
        };

        // Rest of your code to send the release update
    }
}
```

The range of rows you wish to include (in this case, rows 6 through 10) is determined by the **startRow** and **endRow** variables in this example. **Row >= startRow && Row = endRow** tests whether the current row is contained within that range. If so, the code included within the if block will run; else, it will be skipped.

Include the rest of your code to send the release update using the url, payload, headers, and options variables, and be sure to update the targetSheetName variable with the name of your sheet.